# setToolTipText is not showing the tool tip

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, mouseenter

I used this code in constructor of my class.

```
     public CheckComboBox()
     {   
       comboBox.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent mEvt) {
           comboBox.setToolTipText("lakshman");
            setToolTipText("laksman");
           System.out.println("lakshman");
        }
     });
```

when mouse entered happening, println statement prints to the console but other two tooltip methods are not showing relevant tool tips. here combobox is an instance field of swing combobox. what is the reason for settooltip method to not show the tooltip?

Comment: Calling `setToolTipText` does not make a tooltip appear, it only indicates what text the tooltip should display. To make a tooltip appear, you only need to hover the component on which you called `setToolTipText`

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Why set the tool-tip on mouse entry?  I suspect the tool-tip needs the mouse event to not be consumed, in order to know to pop up.

Comment: @gullium:you mean I should bring the mouse onto the component? in case I did that.but it is not showing.

Comment: @lakshman For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @Alya:nope. I want to show the tooltip when mouse hover the component as gullium said. I think I have done mistake using mouseListener as andrew said. I will check it and will response.thanks all

Comment: ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().registerComponent(comboBox)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16280055/2277645 try this

Comment: Code works fine for me using JDK7 on Windows 7. Post your `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

this should be your class A contains main method

```
     public class A {
     public static void main(String args[]){

        form f=new form();
        f.setSize(300,300);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(form.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
         }

      }
```

and this should be your class of containing the components as:

```
public class form extends JFrame{

public form(){
    Panel p=new Panel();
    final JButton b=new JButton("button");

    p.add(b);
    this.add(p);


    b.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent mEvt) {
       b.setToolTipText("lakshman");

    }

});
}
}
```

the imports you must have to use in the class form are:

```
  import java.awt.Panel;
   import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
  import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
```

Try now lakshman brother !

/////////////////!!!!!!!!!/////////////////////////////

(one more thing this the form class can be simplified as)

```
public class form extends JFrame{

public form(){
    Panel p=new Panel();
    final JButton b=new JButton("button");
    b.setToolTipText("HELLO");
    p.add(b);
    this.add(p);



}
```

}

there is no need (not compulsory) to use an actionListener to show the setToolTipText as it can be added just by calling with the reference of component object you want to show it with 
thanks

Comment: your code is work fine.mine also.but I have added that code in between lot of code in the execution path. I think something have gone wrong.I am searching for that

Comment: Ok if it resolves then ok otherwise you may ask another time thanks

Comment: if you fine something useful in the code you must mark it useful to help the others please

Comment: junaid:that is why I upvoted that. but it din't solve my question yet.

Comment: you can show your code if you still have problems So that can Help you